# Get system information using c#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How to get systeminfo of a computer.

1. System Manufacturer:
2. System Model:
3. Bios Version:

Comment: Read in *registry*: e.g. `HKLM\Hardware\System\Bios\BIOSVersion`

Comment: This question should not be "closed as too broad". It is a very specific question with a very specific answer that is provided below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use following to get Manufacturer name, add a reference to `System.Management`.

```
 System.Management.SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery(@"Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");

 //initialize the searcher with the query it is supposed to execute
 using (System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
 {
     //execute the query
     foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
     {
         //print system info
         process.Get();
         Console.WriteLine("/*********Operating System Information ***************/");
         Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "System Manufacturer:", process["Manufacturer"]);
         Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", " System Model:", process["Model"]);


     }
 }

 System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
 System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher1.Get();


foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
{
    if ( ((string[])obj["BIOSVersion"]).Length > 1)
        Console.WriteLine("BIOS VERSION: " + ((string[])obj["BIOSVersion"])[0] + " - " + ((string[])obj["BIOSVersion"])[1]);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("BIOS VERSION: " + ((string[])obj["BIOSVersion"])[0]);
}
```

[SOURCE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c8e8287-3898-4990-a81b-98f6432514b1/how-to-get-system-manufacturer-name-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: It will not bring everything that he needs!

Comment: @PedroAugusto , because i always prefer to post code, instead of link to somewhere, it took time to post me complete code, so i have updated it, can you try the same, let me know, if i miss anything that OP wants!

Comment: Ok friend, now I think the answer is fitting all requisites!

Comment: @mammoth , updated code, now it should work, Earlier i was not sure, what you need.

Comment: Thanks Arindam manufacturer and Model works perfect. Having problem on the bios info says : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: @mammoth , udpated code , please debug through your application, and check value using `quick watch`, i am sure , you can modify/ or get help from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following classes

1. [System.Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [System.Managemement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management(v=vs.110).aspx)

It has been done by others, if you have done a quick google search, it would have easily be found

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362227/System-Information

Answer (score 0):

You can check this site and get all informations that you will need to create your program:

http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_get_bios_info

Of course, I dont which kind of program you will build, so I just provide how to retrieve the data.

Comment: The URL is not longer valid