# How to get cross-platform system model name with .NET 5?

Tags: c#, macos, .net-5

I'm developing a cross-platform application in C# / NET 5, it will run on both Windows and MacOS. I need to print the "manufacturer model name" of the running system. On Windows, this is more or less what is returned by querying the WMI class `Win32_ComputerSystem`. For example the "Name" field:

```
  Caption:  Computer System Product
  Description:  Computer System Product
  IdentifyingNumber:  <hidden>
  Name:  Inspiron 7370  **<--- I need to print this kind of info!**
  UUID:  <hidden>
  Vendor:  Dell Inc.
  Version:
```

The software will run also on MacOS, so I need a common way to retrieve, example, "Apple Mac Mini" or similar string. I assume it won't be possible to get it via WMI.

Is there a cross-platform solution? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Unique System ID on Mac using C#(Mono)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714965/getting-unique-system-id-on-mac-using-cmono)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Not really, it does not seem to be "cross-platform" since it performs system-specific query. Anyway, if this is the only solution, I assume I'd need to have an "IF" condition where, on Win32 I use WMI, on Apple I use that "ioreg" command. Is that true?
Also that example returns the UUID, not the machine model name.

Comment: Even if microsoft would implement platform independent solution for such a minor thing, in background it would be a switch/case what would run different code depending on current os: WMI on windows, `sh` command line tool on mac, whatever on linux, etc. But I doubt they will. You have to do it yourself: check platform, run corresponding to a platform code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get system information using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253423/get-system-information-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've "solved" by branching between the different OS and without needing to use `System.Management` package:

```
public static string GetSystemModelName()
{
    var cmd = new ProcessStartInfo();
    cmd.RedirectStandardError = true;
    cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    if (System.OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    {
        cmd.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        cmd.Arguments = "/C wmic csproduct get name | find /v \"Name\"";
    }
    else if (System.OperatingSystem.IsMacOS())
    {
        cmd.FileName = "sh";
        cmd.Arguments = "-c \"sysctl -n hw.model\"";
    }
    else return null;

    try
    {

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (Process process = Process.Start(cmd))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
            builder.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }

        return builder.ToString().Trim();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```